# How do I check if a JavaScript function returns a Promise?

Tags: javascript, function, promise

Say I have two functions:

```
function f1() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true);
    });
}

function f2() {
}
```

How do I know if `f1` will return `Promise` and `f2` will not?

Comment: First you would need to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to see if it actually returns. Or you can just call it and see what happens.

Comment: I mean if I can have a function to check if f1 is a function returning promise.
isPromiseFunction(f1); //true
isPromiseFunction(f2); //false

Comment: And even if it did return a Promise once there is no guarantee it would next time `function f3(){return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'}`

Comment: ps: I don't want to call it, just to check any function is promise returning or not

Comment: @tranminhtam You can't. That's what all of the comments previous to yours are saying.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: why it can not be, in case if we want to check if it returns Promise or not then just call it later

Comment: @tranminhtam Learn about [usejsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/), specifically http://usejsdoc.org/tags-returns.html

Comment: @tranminhtam It is mathematically impossible to know what a function returns without calling it and wait for it to return value.

Comment: let's get to the point, why you want to know that, and how you possibly don't know what a function you`re calling returns *(in terms of type, not the actual value)*.

Comment: @Thomas: in scenario, I want to check a function returns promise or not in order to handle the function correct as it should be handled.
The function is one of two type.

Comment: Then just call the function and check the type of the return value. In the scenario you're outlining, there's no reason to know without calling it.

Comment: @tranminhtam _"in scenario, I want to check a function returns promise or not in order to handle the function correct as it should be handled. The function is one of two type."_ `let isPromise = possiblePromise instanceof Promise ? possiblePromise : Promise.resolve(possiblePromise)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28123576/

Answer (score 41):

Call the function, use `instanceof`

```
let possiblePromise = f1();
let isPromise = possiblePromise instanceof Promise;
```

Comment: [ps: I don't want to call it, just to check any function is promise returning or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416214/how-to-check-if-a-function-return-a-promise-on-javascript#comment73891478_43416214)

Comment: @AlonEitan Then, here, would try using `RegExp`

Comment: @AlonEitan Alternatively, if `f1` does not return a `Promise` the result of function can still be passed to `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: Believe me, I totally understand your answer, it's the OP I don't understand at all (I didn't downvoted BTW, I actually upvoted - But I did downvoted the question and VTC as "Unclear what you are asking")

Comment: With that you are checking if it's a Promise created with that Promise implementation in particular, if it has been created with another one it's gonna be false even if it returned a valid Promise.

Also I think the OP was asking about knowing if the function returns a Promise without executing it (which is not possible).

Answer (score 16):

So it's just about normalizing the output. Then run it through `Promise.resolve()` and co.

```
var possiblePromise = f1();
var certainPromise = Promise.resolve(possiblePromise).then(...);
```

or

```
var possiblePromises = [f1(), f2()];
Promise.all(possiblePromises).then(values => ...);
```

But you need to have a basic Idea of what these functions return. For Example: Both examples would fail with

```
function f3(){
    return [somePromise, someOtherPromise];
}

var arrayOfPromisesOrValues = f3();

//here you'll still deal with an Array of Promises in then();
Promise.resolve(arrayOfPromisesOrValues).then(console.log); 
//neither does this one recognize the nested Promises
Promise.all([ f1(), f2(), f3() ]).then(console.log);

//only these will do:
Promise.all(f3()).then(console.log);
Promise.all([ f1(), f2(), Promise.all(f3()) ]).then(console.log);
```

You need to know that `f3` returns an Array of Promises or values and deal with it. Like you need to know that `f1` and `f2` return a value or a Promise of a value.

Bottom line: you need to have a basic knowledge of what a function returns to be able to run the result through the proper function to resolve the promises.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.

You can, however, *cast* any function to a Promise-returning function. This is what I'd do here.

```js
const toPromise = function (f) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const result = f.apply(null, Array.from(arguments));
      try {
        return result.then(resolve, reject); // promise.
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
          resolve(result); // resolve naked value.
        } else {
          reject(e); // pass unhandled exception to caller.
        }
      }
    });
  };
};

const f = (x) => x;
const g = (x) => Promise.resolve(x);
const h = (x) => Promise.reject(x);

// Naked value.
toPromise(f)(1).then((x) => {console.log(x)});
// Resolved Promise.
toPromise(g)(2).then((x) => {console.log(x)});
// Rejected Promise.
toPromise(h)(3).catch((x) => {console.log(x)});
```

Comment: _"This can't be done."_ `RegExp` can be used to parse the function as a string

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. Consider the example from the OP comments: `function f3(){return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'}`

Comment: The `RegExp` can be compiled, though it might not be trivial. "can't" implies not possible, where it is possible.

Comment: No. No RegExp can be crafted which guesses the return value of a random function.

Comment: Disagree. Conditional operator can be parsed.

Comment: Ok so does `f3` return a Promise or not? Can you look at it and tell? Hint: No, you can't. The answer is "maybe, depending on the _random_ number returned by `Math.random`"

Comment: @guest271314, how do you determine from `const c = (value) => value < pivot? a(value): b(value)` wether `c` returns a promise or not. Especially if `a` and `b` are enclosed variables and therefore completely out of your reach

Comment: What is f3? Hesitant with term "can't" until all options are thoroughly exhausted, though for some circumstances that could be true - if that is conclusion after trying all known options.

Comment: I imagine it'd be pretty exhausting to write a regular expression that can predict the future.

Comment: @Triptych your `Array.from(arguments)` is flawed, it contains the function itself, and a simple `Promise.resolve(f(/*whateverArgumentsYouWant*/))` will work better than your complicated function

Comment: Yes, exhausting, though possible until shown and proven to be not possible. `RegExp` is one option. There may be other options; that is one have previously utilized. Though the gist of solution to present inquiry is to pass function call to `Promise.resolve()` if the pattern is using `.then()` to get result of function call. There are numerous propositions which have been considered not possible, or "can't" was used to describe possiblilities where those propositions were proven to be not only possible, but extensible beyond previously limited expectations.

Comment: It's impossible in the _general_ case to determine if a function will return a particular value. An example that breaks this concept is given by `f3` in my second comment. Just giving my stance one last time for anyone else reading. There are _some_ functions for which it's possible, but you can't write a a RegExp that will figure this out for _any_ function. If you think you can do it, do it, and collect your Turing Award.

Comment: @Thomas - you're right. Forgot to wrap in a function. Fixed. Nice catch :) Incidentally, this isn't all that complicated if you're used to working with Promises. Try doing the above _without_ using Promises!

Comment: Awards are meaningless. The knowledge itself and application through manifestation in realms are all that matter; from there it is possible to gain wisdom and understanding. No award can convey knowledge, wisdom or understanding. Perhaps the inquiry is deserving of a Question onto itself. One certainty that have found as to what is not possible is setting a `File` at `FileList` object of native `<input type="file">` `.files` property.

Comment: @guest271314 Great idea - you should ask StackOverflow whether it's possible to craft the regex you're describing. Assuming you're interested in gaining this knowledge. If you do, I'll happily donate 150 points for a bounty!

Comment: @Triptych From evaluating feedbacks, apparently have issues, here, at times being either too terse or too verbose at composition of Question, and/or Answer. Or, there is  a possibility that viewer might lack understanding as to language used. Not sure which is correct at each instance. Would prefer to make certain that the text of the Question is the balance between the two. Which specific function are we referencing as to the prospective Question?

Comment: Can you craft a regular expression to determine the return type of the following function, given its text representation: `function f(){return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): false}`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417236/can-a-regular-expression-be-crafted-which-determines-the-return-type-of-a-functi

Comment: @Triptych yes, and no. If you know the how the value is seeded and can obtain the input that will go into the seeding value, then theoretically you can determine the output of `f3`. As for doing it with RegExp, IDK about that. The main problem here, is *determining whether or not it can be determined*.

Good luck re-inventing the JS parser XD

Answer (score 0):

For NodeJS, we can use `isPromise` function from `util/types` built-in module. Link to docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utiltypesispromisevalue).

```js
import { isPromise } from "util/types";

// assume the JS object you want to test is "obj"
isPromise(obj);
```