# Can a regular expression be crafted which determines the return type of a function?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the *text* of the following function:

```
function f3() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'
}
```

Can a regular expression be compiled which to determines the return type of `f3()` call, without actually calling the function?

Comment: I'll donate a 150pt bounty to a thorough explanation of why it's not possible (or a working `RegExp` :)). We're settling a friendly disagreement. Also, can someone point me to instructions on attaching a bounty to a question I didn't ask. Can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: In what way would you want a regular expression to determine the type? A regular expression could (theoretically) parse aspects of the expression but it has no concept of types. Do you mean "can a regular expression be used to extract expressions which I can identify the types of and then use that information to determine the type of the entire function?"

Comment: Where do you want to run the regex? If you want it run on the output that's a different story than looking at the function.

Comment: Note to above comments: I just edited the question to clarify. In particular you can _not_ actually execute the function to determine the return type. You have only the text of the function.

Comment: @Triptych One critical parameter of Question is how can result be verified without actually calling the function?

Comment: @guest271314 Agreed. I'd already edited the question to include that.

Comment: Oh, you're asking? Yes of course this has to be done without executing the function. That was the whole point. Did you not understand that?

Comment: @Triptych Yes, gather the point of Question. Attempting to determine all possible parameters of Question, including probabilities of `true`, `false`, which is not necessarily 50/50. In any event, we should be able to get a conclusive Answer to the inquiry, whatever that definitive Answer is.

Comment: @guest271314 I'll let the SO community handle that one.

Comment: *"Can I use a regular expression to cook eggs?"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the code, we cannot determine the return type of this via regular expressions. Proof by Contradiction:

1. Assume we can find the return type by using a regular expression.
2. The return type is decided in the final line, via a non-deterministic call to `random` (it isn't known ahead of time).
3. Regular expressions are deterministic- they always have the same output when run on the same input.
4. Thus, the function's return type must be static, since we can run a regular expression and find the return type (and that regular expression will always return the same thing).
5. Contradiction: The function's return type must be static, but the function's return type is variable due to `random`

Note: The above assumes the type must be a single one, and does not account for Union types on its own.

Additionally, a proof on why we can't do it always.

1. Assume that somehow we can figure out every type used in the function in some way.
2. At some point, we generate a string `a="A"+Math.random()`
3. At some later point, we generate a string `b="class "+a+"{...}`
4. After this definition, we execute `c= eval("new "+a+"()")`.
5. When we return `c`, no regular expression can know the type- the type is newly named in the function, determined randomly and is different for every execution.

This assumes the question was a more general "can javascript regex find the return type of a generic function." Note that if it were possible to find the return type, it would be possible to tell that the program halts (it can't return if it doesn't halt, and the return type would have to be undefined if it never halts), and the Halting problem is still unsolved.

Comment: What if our type definitions allow for union types? I.e, a valid return type may be `(Promise|string)`?

Comment: @MikeC if that's the case, it becomes much more complicated, though I'd still suspect it can't be done- you'd almost have to check the return statement parsing for a variable or literal, then backreference to that variable's last declaration or mutation, recursively until we find an actual solid declaration (otherwise something like `{a="3";a+=1;return a}` may fail on noting that there's an addition and assume int, while it returns a string). I suspect we might be able to use something like the Pumping Lemma to disprove it, but I'm not 100% on how to follow through on that right now)

Comment: I completely agree with you. Maybe if no one else gets to it by the time I get off work, I'll work out a proof.

Comment: @Triptych I believe I've gotten sufficient proof that this is impossible.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible to programmatically determine the return type of that function using only RegEx. In order to understand what that function does, you need to parse its code. However, JavaScript is a [Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) Type 2 grammar ([context free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)) and RegEx is a Chomsky Type 3 grammar ([regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar)). JavaScript is fundamentally too complex to be parsed with RegEx.

If you're just trying to deal with the fact that you have the function as text and you need to evaluate it, you could use [the eval() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: Eh, but I don't think you can consistently apply "regular grammar" to language implementations of regex. There are many features that are stuffed into language regex frameworks (e.g. lookaround) that are not defined in theoretical regex.

Comment: I have to agree with @KennethK. As much as I hate that people abuse regex and that most people don't understand it was originally meant for regular languages (which are context-free), the meaning has expanded and regex can have context in most of the modern implementations.

Comment: This guy argues that PHP's implementation can match all context-free languages and some context-sensitive languages: https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html. Also, while JS might be recognizable as context-free, I have my doubts that it can be evaluated and / or type-checked without context.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Since the return type is determined on the result of Math.random() and result of Math.random() is not known until runtime. This particular function must be executed in order to know the return type.

Comment: What if our type definitions allow for union types? I.e, a valid return type may be `(Promise|string)`?

Comment: Good comment @Mike. It's obviously impossible to determine whether the result will be  a string or a Promise thanks to the call to `Math.random`. A good static analysis tool ought to be able to determine that it will be one of the two. I think Google's closure compiler can do this already.

Comment: @MikeC Still not in javascript. Function can randomly define new types or modify existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on clarification from OP:

You can certainly get text of a function using f3.toString(). But building reliable regex to parse return value type will never be reliable. The last line in function may or may not be returning a value. In some cases you explicitly have return statements in middle of function. How would you handle that? You will end up twinkling regex for rest of your development cycle

So if I understand correctly, you want to determine what type of value function returned after calling it. Looks like there are two possibilities: a Boolean true and String 'naaah'

You can determine return type using typeof operator:

```js
function f3() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'
}
returnVal=f3()
if ((typeof returnVal)=='string')
  console.log("Got String)
if ((typeof returnVal)=='boolean')
  console.log("Got boolean")
```

If you really really really want to use regex to determine return type:

```
function f3() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'
}
returnVal=f3().toString()
var regex = /^naaah$/;
if (regex.test(returnVal))
  console.log("Got String)
else 
  console.log("Got boolean")
```

Comment: You don't understand correctly. They wish to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to determine the return type of a function.

Comment: While this does what the question's answer should do, and is a significantly better approach, it doesn't answer the question (find with a regex). You also forgot a `"` after your `"Got String`.

Comment: And that boggles my mind. Why would anyone use regex to determine return type of a function?

Comment: Since a regex only works with strings and the return type is not a string the answer is no, you have to do some processing of the return type before applying a regex.

Comment: @alpeshpandya It's an interesting theoretical question and, if proven one way or the other, could alter ones interpreter/compiler construction.

Comment: Ok I added a a way of determining this with regex. But I would never recommend anyone to do it that way.

Comment: @alpeshpandya You're misunderstanding. The idea is not to call the function at all. It's to parse the function, as text, and attempt to determine the return type using that. Pretend that the function is just a string, not an actual function.

Comment: You can certainly get text of a function using f3.toString(). But building reliable regex to parse return value type will never be reliable. The last line in function may or may not be returning a value. In some cases you explicitly have return statements in middle of function. How would you handle that? You will end up twinkling regex for rest of your development cycle.

Comment: @alpeshpandya That's the question though. Can you prove, positive or negative, that regular expressions cannot be used to determine the return type of a function?

Comment: Yes they can be used in theory assuming unlimited development time, no limitation on on-going maintenance time and unlimited tolerance for slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toString()` to convert function to string, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/Math\.random\(\)\s[>]\s0\.5/` to get `Math.random() > 0.5` portion of function, which we call at replacement function of `.replace()` using `Function` constructor.

As it makes no difference when that portion of `f3` is called, we only need the `Boolean` result of `Math.random() > 0.5` to facilitate the conditional operator result.

Again we use `RegExp` to check what `Math.random() > 0.5` returns for only that part of function using `/return\strue/`, `RegExp.prototype.test()` and to get the expected type, either `Promise` or `String`.

We then use `Function` constructor again, passing `return f3`, confident that we have predicted the return type of the function `f3` when called.

```js
function f3() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true): 'naaah'
}

f3 = f3.toString().replace(/Math\.random\(\)\s[>]\s0\.5/, function(match) {
  return new Function(`return ${match}`)()
});

// here we can visually determine whether `true` or `false` is returned;
// though as vision is based on perspective, we make sure of the type
// using `RegExp` at defining `type`
console.log(f3);

// here we determine `true` or `false` using `RegExp`
let type = /return\strue/.test(f3) ? "Promise" : "String";

console.log(`f3 return type: ${type}`);

f3 = new Function(`return ${f3}`);

console.log(f3()());
```

Comment: Of course, another variation is to not redefine `f3`, but rather define a separate function at `.toString()` and `new Function()` calls, for example, `f4` to preserve `f3`, then call `f4`, which would return same result. Redefined `f3` at stacksnippets to demonstrate proof that the result could be "predicted", without directly calling the function `f3`.

Comment: The way to prove this is to rename to f4, then execute both f3 and f4 and compare the result types. If it's the same 20 times in a row, you've done it! Won't happen of course, because the expression `Math.random() > 0.5` might change on each invocation.

Comment: @Triptych The approach evaluates `Math.random() > 0.5` before `f3` function call. In effect getting and setting `Boolean` result before the general `f3` function call. We will predict the result type 20 of 20 times.

Comment: Ok, so write the test and prove it.

Comment: The test is already written. We substitute `f4 = f3.toString()`, `let type = /return\strue/.test(f4) ? "Promise" : "String";`, `f4 = new Function(return ${f4});`, and `console.log(f4()());`. Each time you click "Run code snippet" the predicted return type of `f4` will be the precise return value of `console.log(f4 return type: ${type});`. The same as currently clicking "Run code snippet" at current Answer 20 times; there is no difference from a loop and running stacksnippets 20 times in succession. Not sure how this fact does not prove approach "predicts" `f3` return type using `RegExp`?

Comment: So, in other words you partially execute the function, check that, and then use that to determine what your return type. Since you're partially executing the function, you aren't following the spec (not calling the function). Your regex is contrived, such that it will pull out exactly that conditional and evaluate it to place it back in. @Triptych this *will* tell you what the function will return, but it isn't really using a regex to do it, it just happens to use regex to figure out what to execute (which makes it deterministic for regex to figure it out).

Comment: @Delioth No, not executing the function, evaluating a portion of the function as string using `RegExp`. One must be very careful when describing requirements. Some may tend to consider matters "outside of the box". It is difficult the consider _all_ possible solutions. The initial proposition was that there was _"No. No RegExp can be crafted which guesses the return value of a random function."_. Where at present Answer `RegExp` is used to extract portion of function as string, evaluate that expression, then replace the expression with a `Boolean` representing the result of the expression.

Comment: Exactly- you aren't guessing the return type of the original function. You are finding the return type of a *new* function which happens to be similar to the old function, only the randomness was evaluated. Evaluating a part of the function and executing a part are the same thing. You *execute* the statement `Math.random()`, and *evaluate* whether that is `> 5`. The regex doesn't guess anything, it crafts a partially-evaluated function. That new function **isn't** a random function, and thus does not meet spec. See [this](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @Delioth  No, not guessing.  `RegExp` is used to extract the relevant portion of the function. Without `RegExp` this could be achieved using `String` methods. The point is, the solution is a proof of concept to show and prove the proposition that `RegExp` can be used to determine what the `Boolean` value will be _before_ the function proper is called. Yes, a portion of the function is evaluated. The requirement is to to get the type of return value _before_ the function proper is called, which approach achieves. Thus, it _can_ be done. If requirement needs to be stricter,  change requirement

Comment: @Delioth That is, specify precisely that _no portion of function can be evaluated_ before calling function proper. As Question is currently presented, that is not the case.

Comment: Except if you run your regex portion and then the original function, they may or may not be the same. f3^new is not telling the return value of f3^old , it is telling one of the possible outcomes. You create a new function and *override* the old, and that's the loophole you're trying to jump through. This simply isn't the case, you aren't checking `f3()`.

Comment: @Delioth Not sure how link is related? Favorite from that site is the "5 dollar wrench", which was posted as relief for quantum cryptography that everyone who submits to the "more secure" technology is forced into using these days. Yes, it is the same value as any `f3` call _could_ be, as the resulting `Boolean` as string is still "random"; or as random as `Math.random()` returns. There is no distinction which could reasonably be made from substitution a random `Boolean` for a `Math.random()` evaluation. ~50/50

Comment: @Delioth Again, the critical point is that, generally, individuals might have a presumption of the parameters of a case. Though if not clearly delineated, other individuals will find edge cases. Now, later, those edge cases may be identified as "not the same" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191131/are-there-differences-between-thenfunctionreference-and-thenfunctionvalue, which leads back to the question as to precise clarity as to what the Question is. Once presented, utilize knowledge of the edge cases. It is not possible to place something that is already out of a box back into a box.

Comment: @Delioth Interestingly, you can be as precise and detailed as possible, and individuals will still ignore or omit the exacting requirements that you present - and convey that what you propose cannot be achieved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290467/how-to-improve-efficiency-of-algorithm-which-generates-next-lexicographic-permut. This only leads to more trials of what cannot be done by those committed to doing so. Else, travel to "outer space" could not be possible, setting aside the fact that all earthlings are already in "outer space".

Comment: The parameters are "Take this function and tell what the return type will be." This program will take a guess, but there's a good chance that it will be wrong. If you execute this, then execute the original function, there's no guarantee or even correlation of correctness. On average, it's as correct as saying the function always returns a `string` type. Would a regex that always tells you the function will return a `string` be accepted?

Comment: There is no "then execute the original function". We evaluate the relevant portion of the function then replace the expression with the resulting `Boolean`, then call the replacement function. In essence, we can compose the pattern to pass the function `f3`, extract, evaluate the relevant parts, replace `Math.random()` call with result of the call as a `Boolean`, then call the replaced function, which returns the same "randomness". Except that we are able to be aware of what the "random" type will be by first extracting the relevant portions. The replacement function _is_ the original function

Comment: @Delioth At least that is how this user would and has approached the actual Question. By creating a "proxy" function. Perhaps the requirement should be stricter, to ensure this type of workaround is outside scope of Question. As it stands, from perspective here, the pattern is not exclusive to requirement.

Comment: The replacement function *isn't* the original function. Like you said, it's a replacement. It may be derived from the original, but it isn't the original, it's the original *after it's been partially run*. Notably, the original function is nondeterministically typed, and the new one is deterministically typed. Since there's a major difference, the two aren't equivalent, and anything you know about the new one does not necessarily hold for the old one.