# console.time shows different time running the same function

Tags: javascript, console.log

I use console.time to show the time of the function. But I found that it shows different running time of the same function.

I have simplified my function as below:

```
const findIP = (res) => {
    let arr = []
    arr = res.split(',')
}
console.time('1')
findIP('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0')
console.timeEnd('1')
console.time('2')
findIP('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0')
console.timeEnd('2')
```

The time difference between the two is very large.

[image]

I have tried to run several times. And it still cost different time.

[image]

Comment: If those units really are milliseconds, then that's a tiny difference.  Only 0.181 ms different.

Comment: Then how can I compare different functions with tiny difference using console.time?

Comment: Why would you need to see a tiny difference?  Statistically there is no difference.

Comment: I just want to compare the efficiency of my code. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244744/how-to-compare-the-running-time-between-different-functions?noredirect=1#comment102861577_58244744 said. If it can not be the judgement, then what method can I use?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the answer in the the following link:

> If you run shorten multiple times, the V8 engine has a JIT compiler that will optimize that piece of code so it runs faster the next time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601440

Comment: But when I run the third time or more times, it will show different time too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the argument value, for example

```
console.time('1')
findIP('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0')
console.timeEnd('1')
console.time('2')
findIP('1,2,3,4,43,6,7,8,9,4')
console.timeEnd('2')
```

you will see approx equal time

Reason of that difference is: The browser cache

**Simple Definition**
`browser cache` is a temporary storage area in memory or on disk that holds the most recently downloaded Web pages and/or calculated result.

Comment: Do you know why it is approx equal time instead of completely equal time?