# how to compare the running time between different functions

Tags: javascript, console

First, I want to thanks to Bails for his answer on question [console.time shows different time running the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235219/console-time-shows-different-time-running-the-same-function). But it still confusing me that how can I compare running time of two different functions

Here's the code I have tried.

```
function fun1(arr) {
    let a = 0
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) {
        a += arr[i]
    }
    return a
}

function fun2(arr) {
    let a = 0
    arr.forEach((v) => {
        a += v
    })
    return a
}
let array = []
for(let i = 0;i < 100; i++) {
    array.push(Math.random())
}
console.time('fun1')
fun1(array)
console.timeEnd('fun1')

console.time('fun2')
fun2(array)
console.timeEnd('fun2')
```

We all know that forEach is faster than for. But when I run the code above, I got different results:

[image: result1]
[image: result2]
[image: result3]

Comment: Please don't turn into one of these people who put random stuff on JSPerf, or time their functions in some odd way, get some numbers, then say way A is 20% better than way B.

Comment: Ah, microbenchmarks. (As to which is faster—it depends. `forEach` used to be *slower* than `for`, although that’s changed relatively recently.)

Comment: Then how can I know which way is faster?