# Retrieving List of Transactions with Square API

Tags: javascript, node.js, square

Attempting to return a list of all transactions on my Square account for a given location, however, when I run my code I get back an empty JSON object from the Transactions API. Looking for a correct example of how to pull a list of all transactions and read/save them with Transactions API in javascript.

Here's my code:

```
var SquareConnect = require('square-connect');

var defaultClient = SquareConnect.ApiClient.instance;
var oauth2 = defaultClient.authentications.oauth2;
oauth2.accessToken = "ACCESS-TOKEN";


var TransactionsApi = new SquareConnect.TransactionsApi();
var listTransactions = TransactionsApi.listTransactions(locationId);

console.log(JSON.stringify(listTransactions));
```

The return is simply:

```
>>> {}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to deal with async code synchronously.  You should find out if TransactionsApi returns a promise, and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a great trouble shooting step. But I'm bit new, so how do I check the return of a function?

Comment: The API docs should tell you.  Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416214/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-function-returns-a-promise/43416515