# Map nested array values to Map with functionality to set Map values by array index which will be reflected in nested array by reference

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, multidimensional-array

Given the requirement to create a nested array or arbitrary depth, where the basic data structure is

```
[0, [1, [2, [3 /* , [N, [N+1, [..]]] */]]]]
```

or

```
["a", ["b", ["c", ["d" /* , [N, [N+1, [..]]] */]]]]
```

where `arr` is an `Array` instance and and `map` an `Map` instance the requirement is to map each depth is mapped to a `Map` object, where

```
map.get(2) // 2
```

or

```
map.get(2) // "c"
```

gets the value set at the nested array at index `N` where `N` are the linear indexes of the nested array.

In additions, the requirement is to have the ability to execute

```
m.set(2, "x")
```

which will result in

```
["a", ["b", ["x", ["d" /* , [N, [N+1, [..]]] */]]]]
```

Have been able to create the nested array data structure using `Array.prototype.map()` and two additional `Array`.

Am probably missing a simply adjustment which can be made to achieve the expected functionality. The current code only performs the `m.get(<index>)` procedure.

```js
const treeMap = (tree, props = (!Array.isArray(tree) && typeof tree === "string" 
      ? tree.split` ` 
      : tree), res = [], t = [], m = new Map) => props.map((prop, index) => 
      !res.length // first iteration
      ? res.push(prop, t) && m.set(index, prop) // push first value
      : index < props.length-1 // check index
        ? t.push(prop, t = []) && m.set(index, prop) // `.push()` to `t`, re-declare `t` as `[]`
        : t.push(prop) && m.set(index, t[0])) // `.push()` last value `prop` to `t`
    && [res, m] // return `res`


let [arr, map] = treeMap("a b c");

console.log(arr, map);

console.log(map.get(2));

// console.log(treeMap([...Array(3).keys()]));
// [0, [1, [2, [3]]]]
```

After only two attempts decided to ask for a solution here, instead of simply solving the inquiry for self first. In general, test code several if not hundreds or thousands of times over, before asking a question.

How to achieve the above described requirement?

Comment: `.set` is meant to, essentially, set a property of the current map instance. Calling `.set` on a Map should only set the property of that Map, and shouldn't (and can't) mutate an external object, at least in sane code, unless you overwrite `Map.prototype.set`, which is *really weird*. Is the `map` variable *required* to be an actual `Map`, or can you return an object which *simulates* a `Map` while achieving the other requirements?

Comment: @CertainPerformance A simulation of a `Map` is not restricted. Would initially probably avoid using a `Proxy` to limit the amount of objects needed to achieve the requirement, though using a `Proxy` is not explicitly restricted in the question. The main requirement is being able to set the _nth_ nested array index in linear order by considering the nested array data structure as only a an array of linear indexes `0`-`n`

Comment: @CertainPerformance The code was originally composed to achieve the requirement for a Code Review question [Execute promise tree in order of declaration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211018/execute-promise-tree-in-order-of-declaration) that was eventually posted at SO [Call an array of promises in parallel, but resolve them in order without waiting for other promises to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620494/) with some modifications. Decided to extend the functionality in order to avoid having to traverse a nested data structure to get, set values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd construct a `Map` *internal* to the `treeMap` function, call it `mapOfArrs`, which maps each index to its associated nested array. For example, with an input of `a b c`:

```
mapOfArrs.get(0) // -> ['a', ['b', ['c']]]
mapOfArrs.get(1) // -> ['b', ['c']]
mapOfArrs.get(2) // -> ['c']
```

Then, you can return a psuedo-Map object which, when called with `get(prop)`, accesses `mapOfArrs.get(prop)[0]` to get the associated nested value, while `set(prop)` retrieves the nested array with `mapOfArrs.get(prop)` and assigns the new value to its 0th index, `mapOfArrs.get(prop)[0] = newVal;`.

Due to the internal Map, accessing / modifying any of the nested values will have `O(1)` complexity:

```js
const treeMap = (tree) => {
  const [initialItem, ...restItems] = Array.isArray(tree)
    ? tree
    : tree.split(' ');
  const root = [initialItem];
  const mapOfArrs = new Map()
    .set(0, root);
  // Construct the nested structure, putting the newly created arrays in mapOfArrs too:
  restItems.reduce((a, item, i) => {
      const newArr = [item];
      a.push(newArr);
      // we sliced off the first item for the initial value, so have to increment i by 1:
      mapOfArrs.set(i + 1, newArr);
      return newArr;
    }, root);
  
  const psuedoMap = {
    get(prop) {
      return mapOfArrs.get(prop)[0];
    },
    set(prop, newVal) {
      mapOfArrs.get(prop)[0] = newVal;
      return this;
    }
  };
  return [root, psuedoMap];
};

let [arr, map] = treeMap("a b c");

console.log(arr);
console.log(map.get(0), map.get(1), map.get(2));
map.set(2, "x")
   .set(0, 'zzz');
console.log(arr);
console.log(map.get(0), map.get(1), map.get(2));
```

(`Map.prototype.set` does not have side effects, so the external call of, for example, `map.set(2, "x")` *has* to go through a custom function, rather than through `Map.prototype.set`, for the associated array to be mutated as well)