# Build simple cache in Angularjs service for data provide from http request which return object reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I want build some simple cache in Angularjs service for data provide from http request. Additional I want always get reference to the same object. I prepare example code to illustrate my thinking and problem which I have now.

[jsfiddle code illustrate problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mbury/daxep9ut/1/)

I have service `UsersModel` which provide me user from http request.This user data are shared between controllers. So want to have always reference to same data. I add to him simple logic. Before `UsersModel.getUsers()` call service check if exist any data from previous call, if exist return him, if not do a http request. I inject that service in tree controller. In first two controllers `UsersModel.getUsers()` is call immediately after page load. In last after click on button. 
Problem is when two first controller call `UsersModel.getUsers()` in the same time. Then any cached data don't exist and both do http request After that I have in first two controller reference to different user objects. We can see this clicking on load button.

And now my question. How to make this work for the simultaneous first call `UsersModel.getUsers()` and always have reference to the same object data.

app.js

```
var APP = angular.module('APP', []);
APP.SidebarCtrl = function ($scope, UsersModel) {
    var sidebarCtrl = this;

    UsersModel.getUsers()
        .then(function (users) {
            sidebarCtrl.users = users;
        });
};
APP.ContentCtrl = function ($scope, UsersModel) {
    var contentCtrl = this;

    UsersModel.getUsers()
        .then(function (users) {
            contentCtrl.users = users;
        });
};
APP.FootCtrl = function ($scope, UsersModel) {
    var footCtrl = this;

    function load() {
        UsersModel.getUsers()
            .then(function (users) {
                footCtrl.users = users;
            });
    }

    footCtrl.load = load 
};

APP.service('UsersModel', function ($http, $q) {
    var model = this,
        URLS = {
            FETCH: 'http://api.randomuser.me/'
        },
        users;

    function extract(result) {
        return result.data.results['0'].user.email;
    }

    function cacheUsers(result) {
        users = extract(result);
        return users;
    }

    model.getUsers = function () {
        return (users) ? $q.when(users) : $http.get(URLS.FETCH).then(cacheUsers);
    };
});
```

Index.html

```
<div ng-app="APP">
    <div ng-controller="APP.SidebarCtrl as sidebarCtrl">
        <h1>{{ sidebarCtrl.users }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="APP.ContentCtrl as contentCtrl">
        <h1>{{ contentCtrl.users }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="APP.FootCtrl as footCtrl">
        <h1>{{ footCtrl.users }}</h1>
         <button ng-click="footCtrl.load()" type="button">Load</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle code illustrate problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mbury/daxep9ut/1/)

Comment: seems like built-in angular [cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) is perfect solution of your problem

Comment: Agree with @AndreiVolchenko there's no need for building a new cache implementation when doing http calls

Comment: @AndreiVolchenko When I change 'http.get(URLS.FETCH, { cache: true}).then(cacheBanks)' I got the same data but reference to different object. So it is not solution. I mentioned this in a question.

Comment: @Andrei Volchenko New code for you: [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mbury/daxep9ut/3/)  I have not shared data between controllers with yours solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching a promise object in AngularJS service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744830/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your functions as follows:

```
function cacheUsers(result) {
    return (users) ? users : users = extract(result); 
}
```

and

```
model.getUsers = function () { 
    return (users) ? $q.when(users) : $http.get(URLS.FETCH, {cache: true}).then(cacheUsers); 
};
```

It provides additional cache check after fetch and enables built-in cache for the object.

I suggest you to read http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/