# Angular Promises: Best Practices and Pros/Cons of Different Techniques

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm learning Angular and I've come across two approaches to make calls that return promises. I'd like to know if one approach is better than the other and/or when you would use each.

**First Technique:**

```
function getSomeDataFromServer() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (myData) {
        // call to backend was previously made and myData is already loaded 
        deferred.resolve(myData);
    } else {
        // get data from server
        $http.get(my_url_endpoint).then(function(response) {
            // cacheResult() will set myData = response.data
            deferred.resolve(cacheResult(response));
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Second Technique:**

```
function getSomeDataFromServer() {

    if (myData) {
        // call to backend was previously made and myData is already loaded 
        return $q.when(myData);
    } else {
        // get data from server
        return $http.get(my_url_endpoint).then(function(response) {
            // cacheResult() will set myData = response.data
            return cacheResult(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if your getter function should care whether the data was already available - sounds like a controller should handle it. Another thing: in case the browser caches that http request, your first technique becomes an antipattern.

Comment: The first one is the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) (and fails to forward errors). You also may want to have a look at [Caching a promise object in AngularJS service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744830/1048572)

Comment: Closing as a duplicate of the deferred anti-pattern. I'd probably just do `var cached = null; function getSomeDataFromServer(){ return cached || (cached = $http.get(...)) }` or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always prefer the second option. The first option is an anti-pattern typically seen when the developer doesn't fully understand the nature of promises. Deferred objects (`var deferred = $q.defer();`) are used [when you have some asynchronous code that uses callbacks but needs to work with your promise based code](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds).

Most asynchronous things you do in Angular return promises, so you would typically only use deferreds when working with a 3rd party library that relies on callbacks.

In this example, $http itself returns a promise, so creating a new deferred object is not necessary. Returning the $http promise itself is sufficient.