# How to make a Promise not re-run code when already resolved?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a User Model:

```
export class User extends Serializable{
  id: string; 
  first_name: string; 
  middle_name: string; 
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  image_url: string;

  // mykeyStore
  static store:StoreDatabase = new StoreDatabase("mykeyStore");


... More code...
```

and a `loadProfile()` function to that class which returns a promise.

```
loadProfile():Dexie.Promise<any>{
    let promise = User.store.get('user')
      .then(
        tuple => {
          // Extract User Data from tuple
          let user_data = tuple && tuple.value

          // Fill User attribute for Tuple's value
          for (var attr in user_data) {
            this[attr] = user_data[attr];
          }
        }); 

    return promise;
}
```

How can I structure my code, so that calling `loadProfile` will not always run the `then` if it is already resolved, by calling the following:

```
let user = new User();
user.loadProfile().then( () =>
   console.log(user.first_name)
);
```

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [Caching a promise object in service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744830/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `user.loadProfile()`, a new promise is created. Therefore, the code in `.then()` will always run.

If you want to avoid loading attributes multiple times, you can change your function to this:

```
loadProfile():Dexie.Promise<any>{
    if (this.promise) return this.promise
    this.promise = User.store.get('user')
      .then(
        tuple => {
          // Extract User Data from tuple
          let user_data = tuple && tuple.value

          // Fill User attribute for Tuple's value
          for (var attr in user_data) {
            this[attr] = user_data[attr];
          }
        }); 

    return this.promise;
}
```

Then if you call `user.loadProfile()` when it's already loaded, the code in `.then()` will be executed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `loadProfile` will execute inside code again. To avoid that, you need to store the promise in some variable. For example (es6, cuz i don't know typescript well):

```
// Execute code inside loadProfile and store the promise in some variable
const loadProfilePromise = user.loadProfile();

// Will show Hurray
loadProfilePromise.then(() => console.log('Hurray');

// Will not execute code inside loadProfile again, but will show 'Hurray2'
setTimeout(() => {
    loadProfilePromise.then(() => {
        console.log('Hurray2'));
    });
}, 100);
```

And also, do not forget to handle exceptions and rejects in promises, and log them ;D

Comment: Its also worth noting that any data the promise resolved with will be passed down to any `.then`'s added later, Promises can't 're-resolve' but can be chained to an already resolved promise.

Comment: This won't prevent him from calling `user.loadProfile()` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. This concept work for Typescript too. 
Cheers.