# Sharing a promise (in Redux state.)

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a function that is dependent on a Promise being resolved from an async action (API fetch).

The async action needs to either return the Fetch promise, or return a promise that resolves when the Fetch completes.

However, the Fetch should only happen once.

I could store the fetch promise in a global variable, and return that, but is that an anti-pattern in Redux? Should the Promise be in the Redux store, since it's part of the application state?

Example code:

```
//Should this be in Redux Store?
var promise = null;

myfunction() {
  doAsyncTask().then(() => {
    //Continue
  });
}

doAsyncTask() {
  if(promise === null) {
    promise = fetch('URI');
  }
  return promise;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to know. cache the promise the first time the function is called, and always return that cached promise. btw. why do you need that delayed call to `fetch('URI')` *(doAsyncTask())*? why don't you call it in the first place, save the promise and use it instead of calling doAsyncTask()?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the isFetching flag is in the Redux Store, would you store the Promise in there too?

Comment: don't know I have pretty much no experience with redux. To mind are coming two questions: what kind of store is it? can it handle a promise, or does it need serializable data? and the second thought: how long do you need that promise? is that the right place to store data for that duration? like for example, if it is a global store, and you need that promise only for one module, there might be a better place to store it. But as mentioned, there are devs here with more experience in redux to provide you a proper answer to this question.

Comment: It's an object store, so I presume it can store a promise. I agree with your point about the duration, and that's why I'm hesitant to store it in Redux. However, it's part of the application state, and feels like an Anti-Pattern to have state outside the store. To answer your previous comment, the call is delayed to prevent polluting myFunction as the Fetched data has to be processed etc. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the async fetch for updating the store? In other words, are you using a `thunk` ?

Comment: Yes async fetch should update the store with the response from the API, and uses thunk.

Comment: The question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18745499/6757219
But the real question is where to store 'dataPromise' in the context of a Redux State Container.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method for caching a promise, or basically any computation a function produces, so when the function is called again (after the first time) it will return the last computed value, which in the below case is always the **same* promise (either *resolved* or *pending*).

For your specific needs you can replace the *Promise* with a *fetch* and store it in the `cache` variable.

```js
function myfunction(){
  doAsyncTask().then(RES => {
    console.log(RES);
  });
}

const doAsyncTask = (cache => {
  return function(){
    // when called first time, put the promise in the "cache" variable
    if( !cache ){
        cache = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('foo');
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    return cache;
  }
})();

myfunction(); 
myfunction(); // second call uses the exact same promise
```