# How to wait run block async request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a such situation:

1. Have a service '`MyService`'

```js
function getData() {

  // $timeout(function () {
  if (data) { // What to verify if data exist for not to make a request
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve({
      data: data
    });
    return defer.promise;
  }
  // }, 0);

  return ApiWrapper.resolve('get', 'api/data'); // Just a wrapper for request, return a promise
}
```

2. `Get` `request` to server in `run block` and save response to my service '`MyService`'

```js
getData().then(function(response) {
  MyService.data = response.data;
});
```

3. In `ui-router` `resolve` invoke same method `getData`, but if data already exist, I don't want to make request to the server, I want get stored data from service.
   But situation is that my Controllers do same request few times while loading and app.

How to refactor `MyService` for make only one request to server.
Or, is there any other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching a promise object in AngularJS service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744830/1048572), although I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: thanks, but It almost the same I've got in my solution in getData function, I've got 3 get requests 'couse there is no data yet