# Working with async/await and then() how to save results in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, async-await

I'm practicing my javascript skills doing a joke machine that collects jokes from an API and displays them, my problem is that currently, I'm using `.then()` which is fine, but I want to know how do I get my results in an array that doesn't have to wait for `.then()` like in `fetchJokes().then(jokes => console.log(jokes));`

I used to have a function that navigated the array like this:

```
let counter = 0;
let jokes = [joke1, joke2, joke3, joke4];

function nextJoke(jokes) {
  counter++;
  counter %= jokes.length; // start from 0 if we get to the end of the array
  return jokes[counter]; // give us back the actual item
}
```

That's how it was used before fetching from the API.

And this is my current code:

```js
const url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/5";
const fetchButton = document.querySelector("button[type=button][value=Fetch]");

async function fetchJokes() {
  let jokes = [];
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jokes[i] = data.value[i].joke;
  }
  return jokes;
}

fetchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetchJokes().then(jokes => console.log(jokes));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" value="Fetch">Fetch Jokes</button>
```

So I have figured out how to use buttons and all that jazz, just asking for help on how to pass the object that im receiving from `fetchJokes()` and store it in an Array.

Comment: Well... you're already doing that, it seems.

Comment: yes you are already returning an array from you async method.

Comment: You cannot (should not) store it in a global array like before. What would you want the `nextJoke` function to do when it is called while the request is still loading? A) it has to wait itself - so store a promise for the array in the global variable B) it doesn't get called before the promise fulfills - so just declare it inside the `then` handler

Comment: @Bergi What I'm trying to achieve is to fetch my `jokes` array and use it around my code without having to fetch it every time on every different function, read that you mention that I should not store it in a global array, so maybe my approach is wrong?
Another example is if I try to `console.log(jokes)` outside of the `fetchJokes()` function.

Comment: @Nava You don't have to fetch it every time, it's enough to wait for the same fetch everywhere - you can [store the promise itself in a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745499/1048572). The alternative is to wrap all the code that wants to use `jokes` in a large `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi So basically `.then()` is just waiting for `fetchJokes()` to `return` and not actually calling the function right, and that's because the way promises work?, to what I understand from the post you mentioned, a best practice would be to have my array or whatever response I will work with in a closure(so I don't have it in the global scope)?.

Comment: @ricardoNava `fetchJokes()` is called and immediately `return`s a promise on which the `.then()` method is invoked. Then later, the callback passed to  `then` will get called when the promise fulfills. [No magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) :-) Yes, having the asynchronous result not in the global scope is a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me without modifying the main purpose of the snippet in the question.

```js
let counter = 0;
const url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/5";
const fetchButton = document.querySelector("button[type=button][value=Fetch]");

async function fetchJokes() {
  let jokes = [];
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jokes[i] = data.value[i].joke;
  }
  return jokes;
}

fetchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetchJokes().then(data => (jokes = data)).then(data => console.log(data));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" value="Fetch">Fetch Jokes</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fetch()` to retrieve the url's data. Then you have to transform it to json with `.then((resp) => resp.json())`.

After that, you can store the data inside your `jokes` array.

```js
const url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/5";
const fetchButton = document.querySelector("button[type=button][value=Fetch]");
const nextButton = document.querySelector("button[type=button][value=Next]");
const display = document.getElementById("display");
let counter = 0;
let jokes = [];

nextButton.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //Hide next button

fetchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
    .then(data => (jokes = data.value, //Set the array of jokes
                  fetchButton.style.visibility = 'hidden', //Hide fetch button
                  nextButton.style.visibility = 'visible')); //Show next button
});

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //Show next joke
  display.innerHTML = jokes[counter++ % jokes.length].id + " : " + jokes[counter++ % jokes.length].joke;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" value="Fetch">Fetch Jokes</button>
<button type="button" value="Next">Next joke</button>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: This actually does what I'm trying to achieve, but as some mentioned in other comments I think my doubts are with the global scope of `jokes`, or the lack of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question...If you want to fetch from an async api and not have to use .then or have to wait, then that is not possible.

From what I understand of the question, if you do not want to use .then every time, only fetch when the array is empty (only fetch once):

```
const url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/5";
const fetchButton = document.querySelector("button[type=button]
[value=Fetch]");
let arr = []
let counter = 0;
async function fetchJokes() {
    let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = data.value[i].joke;
    }
}

function nextJoke(jokes) {
    const item = jokes[counter]
    counter++;
    if (counter >=jokes.length){
        counter %= jokes.length;
    }// start from 0 if we get to the end of the array
    return item; // give us back the actual item
 }
fetchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (arr.length == 0){
        fetchJokes()
        .then(()=>console.log(nextJoke(arr)))
    }else{
        console.log(nextJoke(arr))
    }
  });
```

[DEMO codepen](https://codepen.io/floresfxf/pen/OjwaZG)

There are many ways to do this. I would suggest looking more into [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).