# what is a good javascript async initialize/cache pattern?

Tags: caching, promise

For sync code I do:

```
 return opts || (opts = getOpts())
```

To make sure things are easily cached/initialized.

What is the easiest to do this in async/promise pattern?
Currently I have a repeating boilerplate

```
if (result) {
   return Promise.resolve(result);
} else {
   return getResult().then(_result => {
       result = _result;
       return result;
   }
}
```

Which is annoying when done multiple times.
Libraries I find are either unmaintained or offer unfriendly syntax.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: `return opts || await getOpts();`

Comment: Cache the promise, not the data delivered by it.

Comment: I think it should be noted that the idea of lazy initialization (if that's what this is about) is inherently synchronous.  It says, initialize data *exactly when it's needed*.  All we can do with async is *begin initialization* exactly when the data is needed, i.e. initialize the data *after* it's needed.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 that introduces a problem as the promise will resolve just once. There's an assumption that every consumer has to return original result which I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand your point about consumers having to return original result.
As with every promise, the cached promise will settle (resolve or reject) only once (or remaining pending). 
That shouldn't be a problem bacause the cached promise can have multiple consumers - as many as you want - with no constraints on what the consumers do with the delivered data.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 maybe I am mistaken. can you provide a working example?

Comment: Ther are many examples here in StackOverflow. [This one is as good as any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745499/3478010).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a more friendly syntax with the await keyword like this

```
if (!result) result = await getResult();
return result;
```