# Service Worker "fetch reentrancy"

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

I am using the service worker to cache requests made ot a rest service.
The implementation corresponds to 'on network response' described on this page https://web.dev/offline-cookbook/.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function (cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return (
          response ||
          fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            return response;
          })
        );
      });
    }),
  );
});
```

The idea is that:

```
1. caller makes 1st request A
2. service worker intercepts the request A
3. service worker checks whether a request A is in storage -> no
4. service worker sends the request A to the rest service
5. service worker gets the response A
6. service worker stores the response A
7. service worker returns the response A to the caller
...
    8. caller makes 2nd request A
    9. service worker intercepts the request A
    10. service worker checks whether a request A is in the cache -> yes
    11. service worker gets the response A from storage
    12. service worker returns the response A to the caller
```

The problem is that the rest request takes some time to return a response and this scenario where 2 or more requests are made to the rest service can occur:

```
1. caller makes 1st request A
2. service worker intercepts the request A
3. service worker checks whether a request A is in storage -> no
4. service worker sends the request A to the rest service
    5. caller makes 2nd request A
    6. service worker intercepts the request A
    7. service worker checks whether a request A is in storage -> no
8. service worker gets the response A
9. service worker stores the response A
10. service worker returns the response A to the caller
    11. service worker gets the response A
    12. service worker stores the response A
    13. service worker returns the response A to the caller
```

How to have only 1 request sent?

Comment: Cache them. Uh, I mean, [cache the promise itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744830/caching-a-promise-object-in-angularjs-service) (or: [memoize the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744830/caching-a-promise-object-in-angularjs-service) that serves the request), you just have to do that *before* the `fetch` is executed. And you cannot put the promise in the builtin `cache`, and you'll have to choose the resource identifier (URL?) by which your cache is keyed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The momoization of the reponse promise is working fine. I have implemented it on the caller side for now as I am not sure how to do it in the service worker.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using the Workbox libraries, instead of "vanilla" service worker code, [this recipe](https://web.dev/extending-workbox/#handle-simultaneous-duplicate-requests-with-dedupenetworkfirst) might help:

```js
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers
import {NetworkFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

class DedupeNetworkFirst extends NetworkFirst {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    // This maps inflight requests to response promises.
    this._requests = new Map();
  }

  // _handle is the standard entry point for our logic.
  async _handle(request, handler) {
    let responsePromise = this._requests.get(request.url);

    if (responsePromise) {
      // If there's already an inflight request, return a copy
      // of the eventual response.
      const response = await responsePromise;
      return response.clone();
    } else {
      // If there isn't already an inflight request, then use
      // the _handle() method of NetworkFirst to kick one off.
      responsePromise = super._handle(request, handler);
      this._requests.set(request.url, responsePromise);
      try {
        const response = await responsePromise;
        return response.clone();
      } finally {
        // Make sure to clean up after a batch of inflight
        // requests are fulfilled!
        this._requests.delete(request.url);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could then use the `DedupeNetworkFirst` class along with [Workbox's router](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests), or alternatively, use it directly in your own `fetch` handler if you'd rather not use more of Workbox.